# different frame for each cell of UICollectionView

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

what I want to do is,

I am using `UICollectionView` to show my stuff.

What I want is, the stuff that I want to show is coming from server,
It may be in single line or some may be multiple.

I wanted to show the cell frame of `UICollectionView` differently.
Means If data is big then bigger frame of `UICollectionViewcell`
and if data is less then smaller frame of `UICollectionViewcell`.

I tried a lot,
but I am succeed only in having fixed size of frame for `UICollectionViewcell`

How to achieve different frame for each cell according to need.

Is it possible....?

@note :- I am not using any xib.
All is done programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem like you are getting `UICollectionView` wrongly.

Let me say in short You are not suppose to set frame but you need to implement your own `UICollectionViewLayout`.

By default `UICollectionView` use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Which add cell one by one.

But UICollectionView is very power full UI component than that. To open its true power you have to understand  `UICollectionViewLayout`.

Here are some good example of that :

- [RFQUILTLAYOUT](https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout)
- [CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout)
- [CCHexagonFlowLayout](https://github.com/cyrilchandelier/CCHexagonFlowLayout)
- [MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout](https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout)

If you want to learn how to create your ow than have a look at following link:

- [Creating Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html)
- [Custom Layouts: A Worked Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/AWorkedExample/AWorkedExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH8-SW6)
- [Implementing UICollectionViewLayout](http://damir.me/implementing-uicollectionview-layout)
- [UICollectionView custom layout tutorial](http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial)
- [A Springboard-Like Layout With the UICollectionView Class](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-springboard-like-layout-with-the-uicollectionview-class--mobile-13426)

If you need to know overview of how UICollectionView work than read : [NSHipster:UICollection​View](http://nshipster.com/uicollectionview/)
One in depth look in Custom Collection View Layouts : [objc : Custom Collection View Layouts](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/collection-view-layouts.html)

I hope I get u correctly. And this will lead you to right direction.

Comment: Hi CRDave, thanks for your input. Will go for it in detail. thai you very much

Comment: CRDave, it uses arc4random to generate different frame for cell. It gives small frame for first cell, if I run the app again then it gives large frame for same cell. I want frame size to be fixed for cell at each iteration, but every cell must have different size

Comment: It depend on your logic. Some example in this list may use it. But is is not mandatory.